# How to list all public Virtual Machines (EC2) instances of all Regions

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to get a list of all public **Instances of EC2** of any **Region**. I have tried with C#.net, but I am getting a list of my EC2 Instances which I have created in my Region with below code.

```
DescribeInstancesResponse describeInstancesResponse = client.DescribeInstances();
List<Reservation> reservation = describeInstancesResponse.Reservations;
var allInstance = reservation.SelectMany(x => x.Instances).ToList();
```

But my problem is to find out all the instances which I have created or anyone else created(public Virtual machines in Running Status).
Is this possible? Please let me know how it will work?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to connect to each region and then list the instances in that region one at a time.

At the top of your code you will want to get the list of regions:

```
AmazonEC2Client client = new AmazonEC2Client();
DescribeRegionsResponse response = client.DescribeRegions();
var regions = new List<Region>();
regions = response.Regions;
foreach (Region region in regions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(region.RegionName);
}
```

In the foreach section process each region:

```
AmazonEC2Client ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(region.RegionName);
// add your code here
```

Comment: I am trying with this but this is giving me an error in very first line. "'No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured'
".

Comment: Post your entire code. Do you have service account credentials defined?

Comment: Yes I am giving as  AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("key code", "Security Key");
            client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonEC2Client(credentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2);

Comment: But I think it will give me all Instances which I have created. Is this possible that fetching all public instances which I have not created?

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code, I can only guess what you have from your comment. For your last question, I don't understand. You only have access to EC2 instances that you have permission to, not all public instances. That would total in the millions on AWS.

Comment: private string ReadAllEC2Instance()
        {

            DescribeInstancesResponse describeInstancesResponse = client.DescribeInstances();
            List<Reservation> reservation = describeInstancesResponse.Reservations;
            var allInstance = reservation.SelectMany(x => x.Instances).ToList();
            var Id = allInstance.Where(x => x.State.Name == "Running").Select(x => x.InstanceId).FirstOrDefault();
          
            return Id;
        }

Comment: I cannot read source code in comments. Post your source code in your question and not as a comment. Since you are having a problem, post the entire code not a snippet.

Comment: Sorry for Inconvenience. I am posting my code as question.

Comment: With that code I am able to retrieve the EC2 Instances which I have created.